# TFS Query - History section - comments added by date

Tags: tfs

How do I write a query in TFS to show me users that have added comments in the history section of a work item in the past 2 days?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
       Team Project      =               @ Project

And    Work Item Type    =               [Any]

And    History           Contains        MY_KEY_PHRASE

And    Changed Date      >=              @Today - 2
```

Since Contains cannot be null we have to add a value to the History search.

MY_KEY_PHRASE = Whatever you want to put in your comments field, as a standard, to identify changes (such as "comments" or "cc" or "." etcetera).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to use prefix before any comments, so any one need to write comments just write "Comments:" keyword followed by carriage return before his comments and then

Edit the query

Add new criteria as the following:

1. (And/Or)-->   And
2. (Field)--->   History
3. (Operator)--> Contains
4. (Value)-->    Comments

Thanks

M.Radwan